# Getting the WeekdayName + 1

Tags: vb.net, date

I am sure this is very easy but I am having one of those days.  I have the code `Now.Date.AddDays(+1)` which gets me the date for tomorrow but I need the week day name for tomorrow.  Been googling for a while now and just cant seem to find it.

Answer (score 4):

Use [`DateTimeFormatInfo.GetDayName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo.getdayname%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1)

```
Dim tomorrow = Now.Date.AddDays(1)
Dim weekDayName = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.GetDayName(tomorrow.DayOfWeek)
```

You can also use standard datetime format strings:

```
weekDayName = tomorrow.ToString("dddd") ' long '
weekDayName = tomorrow.ToString("ddd") ' abbreviated'
```

[**Standard Date and Time Format Strings: The Long Date ("D") Format Specifier**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1.aspx#LongDate)

Answer (score 0):

Simply:

```
Dim sDayName As String = Date.Today.AddDays(1).ToString("dddd")
```

You could check the available patterns [here](http://www.geekzilla.co.uk/View00FF7904-B510-468C-A2C8-F859AA20581F.htm).